# Data Validation on basis of cell value using EPPlus for .Net

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, epplus

I have two columns where column 1 contains Question and Column 2 contains Answer Type code. There are 2 type of answers viz. Multiple Choice and Yes No. I need to replace these Answer Type code with  Data Validation i.e drop downs. For example, where ever column 2 contains 1 then it should be replaced by Drop Down containing pre-defined options and like wise if it contains 2 then another drop down with Yes-No options.
Following is the code which generates my excel, tried applying Data Validation and it works fine just see code block which adds it for column B:

```
private void GenerateExcel(DataTable dt, string finalFileNameWithPath)
{
    if (File.Exists(finalFileNameWithPath))
        File.Delete(finalFileNameWithPath);

    FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(finalFileNameWithPath);

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("AnswerSheet");
        worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true); //--dt is Datatable containing two columns i.e. Questions and Answer Type Code.

        //--Following code place drop down with 6 options in column B
        var val = worksheet.DataValidations.AddListValidation("B:B");            
        val.ShowErrorMessage = true;
        val.ErrorTitle = "An invalid feedback was entered";
        val.Error = "Please choose feedback from drop down only.";            
        val.Formula.Values.Add("Strongly Agree");
        val.Formula.Values.Add("Agree");
        val.Formula.Values.Add("Neutral");
        val.Formula.Values.Add("Disagree");
        val.Formula.Values.Add("Strongly Disagree");
        val.Formula.Values.Add("NA");

        //-- Following code save excel
        package.Save();
        package.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Can any one help me out in this?